# Unable to make predictions using TensorFlow Go API

Tags: go, tensorflow

I have a MLP coded using Tensorflow Python API. The following is the code snippet:

```
# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 11],name="x")
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None])

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([11, 32], 0, 0.1)),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32, 200], 0, 0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([200, 1], 0, 0.1))
}

biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32], 0, 0.1)),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([200], 0, 0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1], 0, 0.1))
}

# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)
pred = tf.identity(pred, name="pred")
```

The model has been trained and saved using the `saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder` method. The predictions using the Python API can be done using the following code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ["tag"], "/tmp/saved_models")
    my_pred= sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('pred:0')
    predictions = sess.run(my_pred, feed_dict={x: pred_data})
    print("The prediction is", predictions)
```

I am trying to make the same predictions using the Go API using the following code snippet:

```
df := []float32{9.5,0.0,7.5,0.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1505292248.0}
 tensor, terr := tf.NewTensor(df) 
 result, runErr := model.Session.Run(
     map[tf.Output]*tf.Tensor{
         model.Graph.Operation("x").Output(0): tensor,
     },
     []tf.Output{
         model.Graph.Operation("pred").Output(0),
     },
     nil,
   )
```

However, I encounter with the following error:

```
Error running the session with input, err: In[0] is not a matrix
         [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, _output_shapes=[[?,32]], transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_x_0_0, Variable/read)]]
```

Can someone point out the reason for this error?

Comment: I'm not too experienced in this field but I believe `matmul` requires a 2D tensor instead of a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear: `In[0] is not a matrix`.

Your `In[0]` is: `df := []float32{9.5,0.0,7.5,0.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1505292248.0}`

This is a 1-dimensional tensor, not a matrix.

The `matmul` node requires both its arguments to be matrices, thus 2-dimensional tensors.

Therefore, you have to change your `df` definition in order to define a 2-D tensor, like that:

```
df := [][]float32{{9.5},{0.0},{7.5},{0.0},{0.0},{2.0},{0.0},{0.0},{0.0},{0.0},{1505292248.0}}
```

A good reference on how to think/debug tensorflow + go code is: https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/go/2017/05/29/understanding-tensorflow-using-go/

Comment: Thank you for your response. That does solve my problem. However I am still not able to make the predictions on the saved model. I have two dictionaries `weights` and `biases` defined in my program while training my model. Do I need to define it while making the predictions using the GO API as well? Or can I fetch it from my saved model?

Comment: You only have to know the complete name of the nodes you defined in the 2 dictionaries (you can get them printing every item in the dictionary) if you want to fetch the values of the weights and the biases. Also, you don't need this if you only want to do predictions. Your code should work. But this is another question and deserve another thread. You can mark this answer as accepted since it solved your problem and open a new thread with the new one.

Comment: Sure would do that. Thanks!!